# Использование классов и объектов в Java

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Возможно мой вопрос может показаться глупым и очевидным, но всё-таки я вынужден его задать. У меня имеется рабочий код который мне требуется изучить. 
В одном файле

```
import java.util.*;
class trgobjects{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String[]args){

        System.out.println("Ввод числителя: ");
        int up = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ввод знаменатель: ");
        int down = reader.nextInt();
        drob frac = new drob(up, down);
        System.out.println(frac);
    }
}
```

В другом файле

```
class drob{
    public int chisl;
    public int znamen;

    public drob (int mo, int me){
        this.chisl = mo;
        this.znamen = me;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        return (this.chisl+"/"+this.znamen);
    }
}
```

Вопрос собственно вот в чём: смысл метода `toString` во втором классе? Куда он возвращает значение? Когда он действует: при инициализации объекта или при использовании в программе? И в каком порядке действуют методы в первом классе, если их никто не вызывал? И почему этот метод обязательно должен называться `toString` (ибо иначе он не печатает дробь корректно)? И как вызывать методы одного класса из другого?

Comment: @Алексей Швачко Запомни очень ВАЖНУЮ деталь, что классы в Java пишутся с большой буквы. Это must have. Это первое. Во вторых просто почитай замечательную книгу. Называется Философия Java. В ней все подробно описано. Просто почитай и не нужно будет задавать такие вопросы.

Comment: системный вывод `System.out.println` вызывает метод `toString()`, всякий раз, когда от него требуется вывести на экран объект. Этот метод есть у любого объекта и по умолчанию (класс `Object` - "прародитель" всех классов) выводит имя объекта и еще некоторую информацию о нем. В вашем случае метод в вашем классе `Drob` переопределен и выводит какую-то дробь вместо имени. А вообще, как сказали выше - больше читайте, а меньше ждите, когда кто то что то сделает за вас (прочитает и расскажет) - это как бы  основы и программисту стыдно должно быть такое спрашивать, даже если "я еще только учусь"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вверху висит баннер: "Не стыдись спросить - не знать еще постыднее!".

По сути вопросов.

> смысл метода toString во втором классе?

Метод `toString()` есть у каждого класса, т.к. он есть у "суперкласса" `Object`. И его (метода) название говорит само за себя - строковое представление объекта. `Object` просто представляется строкой вида `@xxxxxxxx`, где `хххххххх` - хэш код данного объекта (рандомное число для `Object`).
Когда вы посредством метода `System.out.println(String...)` выводите на экран примитивный тип, например, int, он автоматически представляется в десятичном виде, как мы и привыкли видеть числа (1 -> "1"). А как же отобразить объект? Ведь система не знает как его интерпретировать в строку. Если не переопределить метод `toString()`, будет выводиться `@xxxxxxxx` (см. выше).

Обычно объект имеет состояние (поля) и поведение (методы). Так вот, объект, как правило, можно представить в строковом виде, напечатав его поля. И вот КАК это сделать и какие поля будут представлять ваш объект, решает программист. В вашем примере объект "дробь" представлен числителем и знаменателем (в виде чисел, автоматически преобразованных в строки), разделенными слэшем.

> Куда он возвращает значение?

`toString()` вызывается неявно (без явного вызова), если функция (метод) в качестве параметра требует `String`. Явно тоже можно его вызвать, если вам нужно в строковую переменную получить строковое представление объекта: `String str = frac.toString();`

> Когда он действует: при инициализации объекта или при использовании в программе?

Действует (вызывается) при его вызове (явном иди неявном) - см. выше.

> И в каком порядке действуют методы в первом классе, если их никто не вызывал?

Если методы никто не вызывал, они просто есть в вашем классе и их можно вызвать. Выполняются они в порядке вызова. Может, не совсем точно понял вопрос, но в первом классе у вас один метод `main()`. Он, действительно, не был вызван явно (хотя он такой же метод как и остальные, его можно вызывать, в том числе из других классов и даже рекурсивно). Это точка входа в любую консольную программу (поэтому он и статический - не нужно создавать экземпляр его класса).

> И почему этот метод обязательно должен называться toString

Как уже написали, это метод предка всех предков. Так придумали разработчики Java.

> (ибо иначе он не печатает дробь корректно)

Иначе - это как? Вы можете написать в классе drob любой другой метод (например, `void printDrob() {System.out.println(chisl + "/" + znamen);}`) и вызывать его вместо `System.out.println(frac);` => `frac.printDrob();` - эффект будет такой же.

> И как вызывать методы одного класса из другого?

не статические - через экземпляр класса (`frac.printDrob();`)
статические - через имя класса (`trgobjects.main("args")`)

И, да, читайте классику. Хотя бы Java Code Convention!

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Побольше бы таких людей как вы!

Answer (score 1):

Вам дали плохой код.

Из-за несоблюдения правил именования он плохо читаем. Классы называться должны с большой буквы.

Также пропущена аннотация `@Override` у метода `toString()`, что и не дало вам возможности понять, что этот метод переопределён.

А переопределяют этот метод как раз, например, для вывода к-л значений или представления экземпляра к-л класса в виде строки, что и сделано в этой программе.